# How to create a custom bootable USB from my Ubuntu Server

Tags: 14.04, server, live-usb

I want to create a bootable USB of my Ubuntu Server but I am unsure of how to do this. I need to be able to package everything in my Server to a iso or img to create a bootable USB to install everything with not user input. How can I do this without a GUI? Thank you.

Comment: Physical server or virtual server?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ***portable minimal installed system with a text interface*** in the same way as I did according to the following link.

You can also take a short-cut and start from an uploaded compressed image file (that you find in the following link), install it with ***mkusb*** and add your own program packages and tweaks. Finally you can create your own image and distribute it.

[Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)